# _User Class objects do not show up on the Parse web browser

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, mlab

The browser shows the correct no of objects in the _User class ([Parse Browser 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXeI8.png)) but does not show any data ([Parse browser 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP2Hu.png)). Although the data is there when I check on the mongoLab on Heroku.

I do not know if this is related but querying the _User class is taking unusually long time. Here's a sample log for the _User class -

*2016-08-03T18:46:22.110230+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/_User" host=xxxapp.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx fwd="xx.xx.xxx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms **service=4187ms** status=200 bytes=8287208*

Compared to querying some other table -

*2016-08-03T18:46:53.665939+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/Messages" host=xxxapp.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx fwd="xx.xx.xxx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms **service=74ms** status=200 bytes=2087*

This excess time taken in querying the _User class started after I was not able to view the objects of the _User class on the browser.

Comment: which parse-dashboard version  you are using ?

Comment: Hi Ran, I'm using 1.0.13 version

Comment: can you please update to the latest 1.0.15 and check it again ?

Comment: Hi Ran, I tried with 1.0.15 but the problem persists. By removing a user who was logged in when this error occurred, I'm able to get the _User class showing up on the browser. After further debugging I  figured that it might be because of a PFFile entry. I'm not sure though.

Comment: S like I guess this is a bug. Maybe you can open a new issue on parse server github page. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: Hi Ran, thank you for all the help. Yes, I can reproduce the bug. It is caused due to a mismatch of the type of value. I was putting in a NSData value instead of the expected PFFile type. I will also open a new issue on the github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is caused when one attempts to save a PFObject with the wrong value types. In my case I was attempting to save NSData instead of PFFile. The data shows up on the web browser if you delete the faulty PFObject from MongoLab.